# Nodejs websocket server

Tags: node.js

I found a simple websocket server in  nodejs.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
  wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 8080
  });

var clientsCount = 0;

console.log('clients,rss,heapTotal,heapUsed');

setInterval(function() {
  console.log('%d,%d,%d,%d', clientsCount,
    process.memoryUsage().rss,
    process.memoryUsage().heapTotal,
    process.memoryUsage().heapUsed);
}, 10000);

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  clientsCount++;
  console.log(clientsCount);

  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  });

  ws.send('something');

  ws.on('close', function() {
    clientsCount--;
  })
});
```

The script works fine but sometimes when a client connects and sends a data, the server doesn't accept the message;  `ws.on('message', function(message){...});` doesn't seem to trigger when the event occurs.

Comment: what about , client code? can you share?

Comment: client and server code taken from https://gist.github.com/nicokaiser/2152933

Comment: then Im surprised as you are, that this is happening. Sorry , dude.

Comment: Try build your websocket based on HTTP , I mean something like this
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const http = require('http');
const httpServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Response from server!');
}).listen(8080);

  wss = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,
    port: 8080
  });